# Caster wheel "drives" the robot instead of following it

Tags: gazebo, simulation, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone:

You may be familiar with my robot and its problems by now... here comes a new one, yay!

I think that I'm going to let the problem self explain with [a video](http://bit.ly/MOjdk8). As you can see, on ~0:30 I turn the robot 90º and then, when I tell the robot to go straight forward again, the caster wheel oscillates instead of just following the main body of the robot, making the robot move more like a snake than a car.

Hints?

Thanks a lot,
Miguel.

**Update**: I've noticed that if I add a lot of weight to the caster, the oscillation tends to stabilize, but I don't think that's a solution, because I'm increasing the weight of the caster wheel by 300 times its original weight (3g to 0.9kg). Any other ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38209/caster-wheel-%22drives%22-the-robot-instead-of-following-it./) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I managed to solve this problem by changing the <inertial> matrix to something smaller... but since I'm not familiar with this calculations, I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Anyway, it seems to work pretty well now, so I'm not touching it anytime soon :)

---

Originally posted by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) with karma: 202 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0